# GoogleAPIClient cannot be resolved for AndroidX

Tags: android, google-api-client, androidx

While migrating the android project to ANDROIDX, all the design and support libraries migrated to Androidx but Google api client is still showing error:-

```
 error: incompatible types: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

at this line:-

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                .enableAutoManage(activity, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
```

The activity used in this is an object of `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`

Comment: `GoogleApiClient` is `deprecated` ...so most likely it wont support `androidx....FragmentActivity`

Comment: Can u suggest what should be used in its place...?

Comment: Use [GoogleSignInOptions](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

Comment: Start from .. here .. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client you can `individually` access each `Google Api` without using `GoogleApiClient`

Comment: @ADM Thanks.... Can u also suggest if we can use facebook login api's with androidx